# fail2ban banned IP still able to connect

Tags: server, ssh, fail2ban

Having trouble with Fail2ban:

**Background:**

- Using Ubuntu Server 18.04.2
- Installed ufw
- Installed and set up ssh with keys, random port other than 22, working
- Installed fail2ban

**Issue:**
On same LAN connecting from one computer to the server. using

```
sudo cat /var/log/fail2ban.log | less
```

I can see that it bans that computer's IP when trying to ssh in as root user with randomly typed passwords. BUT, when then using ssh to log in as the user who's key is stored in server, I can log in... from same IP!

**Expected:**
Not being able to log in from that IP, even with right credentials due to the former ban of the IP with several bogus attempts. Having to "unban" that IP first.

Comment: Check that fail2ban properly emitted an iptables rule for that ip.

Comment: Is it banning the **correct TCP port**? You mentioned a "port other than 22" in your question.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/382891/470071). It is concerning the SSH actual port number, just like @FedonKadifeli suggests.